# ajax post then get file to use

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new on php, and I am writing a code which allows me to send some data to php then doing some `exec()`, and then get the process output back to use(e.g. post one web page).

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'some.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: someData,
        async: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#showonscreen').html(html);
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
```

and on php part is like

```
<?php
/*something like $cmd here*/
    exec("$cmd $target_file $Output_fileName $upper $lower");
    echo "<br/>done";
?>
```

after that exec() generates a output file (e.g image)with that Output_fileName under the root folder.
My question is can I get(or load?) this file directly back client side to use?(in success part?)  Or I need a  $.get to request from server again to get that file?

So, on client side, it works like, they upload a image, then click button to process it, then the result image is store under server root, then grab from it to show on the web page.

any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On Server Side**

First its good if you capture o/p like below

```
exec('your_command 2>&1', $outputAndErrors, $return_value);
```

Then

```
if (!$return_value) {

    // Ok lets decide what next

} else {

    // Ooops some problem error handling
}
```

As you mentioned if you are dealing with image then

```
echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($your_file_generated));
```

for plain text you can just

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

echo file_get_contents($your_file_generated);

 // OR

echo readfile($your_file_generated);
```

**On Client Side**

```
$.ajax({
    ..
    ..
    success: function (server_response) {
        $('#showonscreen').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,'+ server_response +'"/>');
    },
    ..
    ..
});
```